# Cannot stop animation on Viewholder item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-viewholder

I'm having a hard time trying to stop animation on an item in my ViewHolder when scrolling the view away: When the view becomes visible, the animation works fine. However, when I scroll the view away and later come back to it, the animation is hung and cannot restart properly. Please see the [visual demo](http://recordit.co/vdVeQnGwki) (around second 17)

I've tried a few ways to stop the animation, but none of them works. My current implementation is in the following.

In my adapter:

```java
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(BaseViewHolder holder) {
    if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
        holder.cancelAnimation();
        holder.setupAnimation();
    }
}

// cancelAnimation method in my ViewHolder
public void cancelAnimation() {
    if (myAnimatorSet != null) {
        myAnimatorSet.removeAllListeners();
        myAnimatorSet.end();
        myAnimatorSet.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please watch the video at 17 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Perform [`View#clearAnimation()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#clearAnimation()) on the view that is being animated.

```
    holder.someView.clearAnimation();
```